# R ggplot - include lower and upper bound for y-axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot in R to represent my data into a plot. The problem is the lower and upper bound of the y-axes (0 and 1.45) are not included

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(User= numeric(0), Time= numeric(0), 
                   Category= character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data[1,] <- c(1,0.42,"Category 1")
data[2,] <- c(2,0.63,"Category 1")
data[3,] <- c(3,0.50,"Category 1")
data[4,] <- c(4,0.72,"Category 1")
data[5,] <- c(4,0.73,"Category 2")
data[6,] <- c(5,0.60,"Category 1")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data= data, aes(x=User, y=Time, fill= Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you make your data frame. When you put in `c()` numbers and characters, numbers are made to character. You can see using `str()` on your data frame.

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ User    : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ Time    : chr  "0.42" "0.63" "0.5" "0.72" ...
 $ Category: chr  "Category 1" "Category 1" "Category 1" "Category 1" ...
```

Making your data frame directly will give corect format and corect plot.

```
data<-data.frame(
      User=c(1,2,3,4,4,5),
      Time=c(0.42,0.63,0.5,0.72,0.73,0.6),
      Category=c("Category 1","Category 1","Category 1",
                "Category 1","Category 2","Category 1"))
str(data)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ User    : num  1 2 3 4 4 5
 $ Time    : num  0.42 0.63 0.5 0.72 0.73 0.6
 $ Category: Factor w/ 2 levels "Category 1","Category 2": 1 1 1 1 2 1
```

Comment: Even doing `data[1,] <- list(1,0.42,"Category 1")` (using `list()` rather than `c()`) would work, but I agree that building a data.frame that way (row by row) isn't a good idea in general.